# Question about VV and HH polarizations in radar

Tags: remote-sensing, soil-moisture, radar, radiative-transfer

I am doing something with [ASCAT](https://www.ospo.noaa.gov/Products/atmosphere/ascat/) which is measuring backscatter to reflect the status of soil moisture. Some research indicated that VV polarization is much more suitable for soil moisture measurement than HH. Why is that? I only know that the electro vector of VV is within the vertical plane of the oscillation of the microwave. But why is it more suitable for soil moisture?